# Not able to start FIM Services

Tags: fim

I am trying to configured new SharePoint 2013 SP1 farm environment on one VM and another VM has sql server 2014.
I am getting an issue when trying to start FIM service and FIM synchronization service form window service panel.
Can anyone please point me to step by step process of setting up FIM services. Additional knowledge on what it does will be even more helpful.
Thanks
Hitesh

Comment: Please look (search this forum) for all the other questions asked about FIM.

Comment: why you starting them manually from services? why not start them from Sharepoint? what error you are getting? check the event log for more clue and share it

Answer (score 0):

Although listed as SharePoint 2010, the guide at http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx is the best place to start!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the following articles which were really helpfull.

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Eventhough it refers to SharePoint 2010 it works for SharePoint 2013